# How to update SharePoint Online site page canvascontent1 using PnP powershell module

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm trying to update several embedded URL links on multiple site pages, across several site collections, within our SharePoint Online (SPO). I've tried this code below, and the retrieval of canvascontent1 is good, but saving the update fails to push thru.

What am I missing? Thank you

```
# Connect to the SharePoint Online Site


$credential = Get-Credential

$fullURLs = @() # pulled site page urls earlier

$badUrls = @() #pulled earlier

$correctLinks = @() # pulled earlier to replace with

foreach($site in $fullURLs){

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site -Credentials $credential

$list = get-PnPlist -identity SitePages

$page = get-pnpclientsidepage $site

$pageItem = get-PnPlistItem -List $list -Id $page.PageId

$htmlCode = $pageItem.fieldvalues.canvascontent1

for ($i=0; $i -lt $badUrls.length; $i++) {

     $htmlcode = $htmlcode.replace($badUrls[$i], $correctLinks[$i])

     Set-PnPlistitem -list "Site Pages" -identity $page.PageId -Values @{"Canvascontent1" = "$htmlcode"}

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to update the links from single web part or multiple web parts on the page?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP thank you for your reply. I'm actually trying to update all URLs in the canvascontent1 object. Not just web parts, all web parts and everything in the canvascontent1, that matches the "$badURL" elements in the array. Thanks again

Comment: The field CanvasContent1 in your value object has a lower case c. Shouldn't it be: @{"CanvasContent1" = "$htmlcode"?

Comment: @Danny thanks for your input, but that above was just a typo on my part. In my Powershell ps1 file, the last line to set the change is @{"CanvasContent1" = "$htmlcode"}

Comment: I think there still is a bug in updating CanvasContent1 with REST. See: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3526

Comment: I also can't retrieve the value of my CanvasContent1 field

Comment: Which version of PnP.PowerShell are you using? I have PowerShell 7 and upgraded to PnP.PowerShell version 2.3.0. With that version I can get the CanvasContent1 field value from SharePoint. And I can also update the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your example and it was also not working for me. I upgraded to PnP.PowerShell 2.3.0 (PowerShell 7) and then it works.

Comment: thank you Danny! upgrading my Powershell and PnP module to 7 gave me the ability to save to CanvasContent.